# a:active link is not working

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="30"><a class="doll" href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/cr/USD"></a></td>
    <td width="30"><a class="eu" href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/cr/EUR"></a></td>
    <td width="30"><a class="pou" href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/cr/GBP"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and listed my css

```
a.doll:link{background:url(../images_en/dollar.png) no-repeat; width:27px; height:27px; float:left;}
a.doll:hover,a.doll:active {background:url(../images_en/dollar_active.png) no-repeat; width:27px; height:27px; float:left;}
a.eu:link {background:url(../images_en/euro.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
a.eu:hover,a.eu:active {background:url(../images_en/euro_active.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
a.pou:link {background:url(../images_en/pound.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
a.pou:hover,a.pound:active {background:url(../images_en/pound_active.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
```

here i can see the :hover is working but not in case for ;active

Comment: `:active` is triggered *while* the link is being clicked (or otherwise activated), not between the click and the change of page. Since you can't click it without hovering it as well, you'll only see the active state if you move the focus to the link and then activate it with the enter key.

Comment: @MassivePenguin, you realize that [_“the :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.”_](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) … so it has nothing to do with how fast your server answers.

Comment: CBroe - my bad. Have deleted comment so not to confuse the matter further.

Comment: perhaps you have defined the wrong class here a.pou:hover,a.pound:active ...see to it

Comment: I want same effects in hover and active state and i got the result when i hover on the button. but once clicked and mouse out it goes to the normal sage. That is the issue i'm facing.

Comment: @BineshPB, check my answer, you can't do that with just CSS, you'll need PHP (or JS).

Comment: Better use jqury to make it active

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo class `:active` is only triggered when the link is clicked (while holding down the mousebutton), check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4XjYV/).

If you want to highlight the link of the page that is active at that moment, you will need to create an additional "active" class. Since you use PHP, you can determine server side which page is the active one and echo the class into that page link.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
a.doll:link{background:url(../images_en/dollar.png) no-repeat; width:27px; height:27px; float:left;}
a.doll:hover{
}
a.doll:active {background:url(../images_en/dollar_active.png) no-repeat; width:27px; height:27px; float:left;}
a.eu:link {background:url(../images_en/euro.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
a.eu:hover{
}
a.eu:active {background:url(../images_en/euro_active.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
a.pou:link {background:url(../images_en/pound.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
a.pou:hover{
}
a.pou:active {background:url(../images_en/pound_active.png) no-repeat; width:28px; height:28px; float:left;}
```